# How to merge lines in groups of three

Tags: awk, sed, xargs, tr, paste

I have a file containing the below pattern, up to 2000 lines.  For every group of three lines, the pattern repeats with different numerical values, but text values at the beginning are common up to the end of the file.

Here I need to merge set of three lines

Input like below

```
ABC 1223334
Days 344678544324677
Base 45666
ABC 1234565
Days 234567899765443
Base 456643
```

Need output looks like

```
ABC 1223334 Days 344678544324677 Base 45666
ABC 1234565 Days 234567899765443 Base 456643
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that the input is in Unix text format. If you are working with DOS/Windows text format files, then first convert these to Unix text files using, e.g., `dos2unix`.

For tab-delimited output:

```bash
$ paste - - - <file
ABC 1223334     Days 344678544324677    Base 45666
ABC 1234565     Days 234567899765443    Base 456643
```

For space-delimited output:

```bash
$ paste -d ' ' - - - <file
ABC 1223334 Days 344678544324677 Base 45666
ABC 1234565 Days 234567899765443 Base 456643
```

The `paste` command, when used with three dashes, as shown above, creates three columns of output, where each column is read from a line in the input. The columns are delimited by tabs by default or with whatever character is used as the argument to the `-d` option.

Answer (score 1):

Like this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{if (NR % 3 == 0) {print}else{printf "%s ", $0}}' file
ABC 1223334 Days 344678544324677 Base 45666
ABC 1234565 Days 234567899765443 Base 456643
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%3 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
ABC 1223334 Days 344678544324677 Base 45666
ABC 1234565 Days 234567899765443 Base 456643
```

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of assuming all records have 3 lines, you could decide the previous record is full when the first field matches the first field in the first record:

```
awk '
  {
    if (NR == 1)
      first = $1 ""
    else if ($1 == first)
      sep = ORS
    else
      sep = OFS
    printf "%s", sep $0
  }
  END {if (NR) printf "%s", ORS}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simplistic shell loop,

```
while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -r b && IFS= read -r c
do
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"
done
```

Output

```
ABC 1223334 Days 344678544324677 Base 45666
ABC 1234565 Days 234567899765443 Base 456643
```